# Why is an LLC converter designed to operate in the ZVS region? how does the Resonance in the LLC circuit contribute to low "MOSFET losses"?

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, resonance, switching-losses

1. For the first question I understand that operating in the ZCS region can result in shoot through but why does that happen?
2. I understand that an LLC converter uses the leakage inductance of the transformer as a circuit component and design the circuit around that, but how does it help in reducing MOSFET losses particularly.

Please Explain.

Answer (score 1):

> For the first question I understand that operating in the ZCS region can result in shoot through

No, it doesn't. LLC converters' secondary side elements (diode or SR switch, doesn't matter) utilise zero-current switching (ZCS) and improve efficiency.

Did you mean "hard switching" here?

> I understand that an LLC converter uses the leakage inductance of the transformer as a circuit component and design the circuit around that ...

Not always. \$LLC\$ stands for inductor-inductor-capacitor i.e. the resonant tank comprises two inductors and one capacitor. You can use the leakage as one of the \$L\$s, and use the primary magnetising inductor as the other \$L\$. This is called "resonant tank with integrated magnetics". But you don't have to do like that i.e. you can design a very low-leakage transformer and use an external inductor. There are advantages and disadvantages of using the leakage as part of the tank, but they are out of your question's scope now.

> ... but how does it help in reducing MOSFET losses particularly.

There's no direct relation. Reducing MOSFET losses relates to the ZVS operation which happens automatically when the tank operates in inductive region.

You should first study and try to understand ZVS and ZCS.

Comment: I have looked at ZVS and ZCS, but when you say "ZVS operation which happens automatically" what is actually happening in the inductors and capacitor on the primary side that makes ZVS in MOSFET?

Comment: @SudhanvaGokhale for a half-bridge LLC, bridge node capacitance (which is the total capacitance i.e. switch output capacitances + stray capacitance coming from the build, seen across the half-bridge node and the GND) gets charged up to supply voltage when one of the switches is on. During the dead time (i.e. both switches are off) the circulating current(s) deplete this capacitor. So a switch has almost zero voltage across it before turn on. If the tank operates in inductive mode (i.e. voltage leads current) this happens, otherwise can't.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation, I appreciate it.